# having shared_ptr as a parameter of a function

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am still having a hard time understanding why

```
void work_with_foo(shared_ptr<foo> _foo);
```

is not recommended compared to

```
void work_with_foo(foo* _foo)
```

I understand that `work_with_foo(foo& _foo)` is better, but a pointer as a parameter! What if someone calls `delete _foo`?

Can someone explain me why?
I always use `shared_ptr`, so for example, in my code...

```
shared_ptr<foo> ptr_foo(new foo);
//calling work_with_foo which takes foo pointer
work_with_foo(ptr_foo); //will  this even work?
```

Comment: Swings and roundabouts - a function should be allowed to assume its arguments remain valid for the length of the call.

Comment: This will give an extensive answer to your question: [Herb Sutter: GotW #92, Smart Poitners as Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Comment: "What if someone calls `delete _foo`?" What if someone calls `delete _foo.get()` on your `shared_ptr`? In a codebase that consistently uses smart pointers, it should be understood that raw pointers never have ownership - they function as a reference that might be null, or as an iterator over a raw array. Nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

If the function being called is only operating on an existing object and will not be taking (shared) ownership, passing by `shared_ptr` is a bit misleading. It would also have an additional cost of reference counting compared to passing an object referece.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if the function you want to pass the object to doesn't require any ownership transfer, the best way is:

```
void work_with_foo(const foo& _foo);
```

or make that

```
void work(const foo& _foo);
```

And at the call site, dereference the `shared_ptr`.

If your function needs to modify the object pointed to, remove the `const`. Note this also works with base class pointers and inheritance etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think passing a `shared_ptr` is "not recommended"?  Who recommends against it?

The one thing that's important to note is that passing a `shared_ptr` by const-ref may be preferable, in that you will avoid incrementing the reference count before and decrementing it after calling the function.  So perhaps passing a `shared_ptr` by value is not great in some cases, but that doesn't mean you need to fall back to raw pointers.

Comment: Passing a `shared_ptr` object around implies copying ownership, and incurs a penalty otherwise not necessary.

Comment: What penalty does it incur (if you pass a shared_ptr by const-ref)?

Comment: I wasn't talking about passing a reference to it. You imply no one would recommend against passing the `shared_ptr` object around. I disagree. The penalty of passing a `shared_ptr` by value is the refcount update, which may or may not block threads if the object is being accessed concurrently.